# Deserializing an API response

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, serialization

I've searched around here on stackoverflow, and on Google for an answer to a problem I'm having.
I've been trying to deserialize a json response http://pastebin.com/d9wZpiYV from this url:

http://ponyvillelive.com/api/nowplaying/index/id/22

I'm able to get a json reulst using the following code:

```
Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://ponyvillelive.apiary-proxy.com/api/nowplaying/index/id/{id}"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "GET"
request.ContentLength = 0
Dim responseContent As String
Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
End Using
```

All the information that I need to extract from the result is:
"station"
"id"
"name"
"genre"
"image_url"
"stream_url"
"artist"
"title"

The main example I've tried is [Deserializing JSON String to VB.net Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629812/deserializing-json-string-to-vb-net-object), but, I'm still quite a novice with vb.net.
If anyone could help me out I'd be extremely greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model JsonClass that corresponds to your Json object to properly deserialize. The fields that you need are in nested json object in json response. Based on Json response that you get from the url, I created a class that maps to the response. FYI, below is the json response

```
 {
 "status": "success",
 "result": {
  "station": {
   "id": 22,
   "name": "Wonderbolt Radio",
   "shortcode": "wonderbolt_radio",
   "genre": "Rock Music",
   "category": "audio",
   "type": "shoutcast2",
   "image_url": "http://ponyvillelive.com/static/stations/20131020_222721_679_image_url_1.png",
   "web_url": "http://wonderboltradio.com/",
   "stream_url": "http://pvlradio.bravelyblue.com:8062/stream?sid=1;stream.nsv",
   "twitter_url": "",
   "irc": "#wonderboltradio"
 },
 "listeners": {
   "current": 0,
   "unique": 0,
   "total": 0
 },
 "current_song": {
   "id": "633ab2e87847a5dd77a385f83022aef9",
   "text": "Sicknessia - Magic",
   "artist": "Sicknessia",
   "title": "Magic",
   "score": 100,
   "sh_id": 1364278,
  "vote_urls": {
    "like": "http://ponyvillelive.com/api/song/like/sh_id/1364278",
    "dislike": "http://ponyvillelive.com/api/song/dislike/sh_id/1364278",
    "clearvote": "http://ponyvillelive.com/api/song/clearvote/sh_id/1364278"
  },
  "external": []
},
```

Code below should work for you.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

Public Class JsonParser
Public Shared Sub ParseJson()
    Const url As String = "http://ponyvillelive.apiary-proxy.com/api/nowplaying/index/id/22"
    Try
        Dim jsResponse = LoadJson(Of JsonClass)(url)

        Dim id = jsResponse.result.station.id
        Dim name = jsResponse.result.station.name
        Dim genre = jsResponse.result.station.genre
        Dim imageUrl = jsResponse.result.station.image_url
        Dim streamUrl = jsResponse.result.station.stream_url
        Dim artist = jsResponse.result.current_song.artist
        Dim title = jsResponse.result.current_song.title
    Catch e As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Could not call webservice")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Shared Function LoadJson(Of T)(uri As String) As T
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000

    Using httpResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()
            Dim jsonSerializer = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(T))
            Dim obj As T = DirectCast(jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream), T)

            Return obj
        End Using
    End Using
 End Function
 End Class

Public Class JsonClass
 Public Property result() As Result
    Get
        Return m_result
    End Get
    Set(value As Result)
        m_result = Value
    End Set
 End Property
Private m_result As Result
End Class

Public Class Result
 Public Property station() As Station
    Get
        Return m_station
    End Get
    Set(value As Station)
        m_station = Value
    End Set
 End Property
 Private m_station As Station

Public Property current_song() As CurrentSong
    Get
        Return m_current_song
    End Get
    Set(value As CurrentSong)
        m_current_song = value
    End Set
End Property
  Private m_current_song As CurrentSong
End Class

Public Class Station
Public Property id() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_id
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_id = Value
    End Set
 End Property
Private m_id As Integer
Public Property name() As String
    Get
        Return m_name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_name As String
Public Property genre() As String
    Get
        Return m_genre
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_genre = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_genre As String
Public Property image_url() As String
    Get
        Return m_image_url
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_image_url = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_image_url As String
Public Property stream_url() As String
    Get
        Return m_stream_url
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_stream_url = Value
    End Set
 End Property
 Private m_stream_url As String
End Class

Public Class CurrentSong
 Public Property artist() As String
    Get
        Return m_artist
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_artist = Value
    End Set
 End Property
 Private m_artist As String
 Public Property title() As String
    Get
        Return m_title
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_title = Value
    End Set
 End Property
 Private m_title As String
End Class
```