# HttpWebRequest: How to dynamically store variable in JSON array format

Tags: json, vb.net

I have my `HttpWebRequest` body that needs to be in JSON array format and I have to populate it dynamically at run time.

```
Dim body As String = "{""studentForm"":[{""title"":""Law Major"",""description"":""Excellent Student. Work hard. Very Intelligent, and so on..."",""phone"":""0123456789"",""categoryId"":1197,""categoryName"":""Senior Student"",""parentCategory"":9,""location"":{""latitude"":45.151053,""longitude"":-79.398193,""radius"":1000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageUrls"":[]}]}"
```

So I need to have variables like `varTitle`, `varDescript`, `varDescript`, and so on into the JSON array. I tried to do that the below way but doesn't work.

```
Dim body As String = "{""studentForm"":[{""title"":varTitle,""description"":varDescript,""phone"":varDescript,""categoryId"":1197,""categoryName"":""Senior Student"",""parentCategory"":9,""location"":{""latitude"":45.151053,""longitude"":-79.398193,""radius"":1000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageUrls"":[]}]}"
```

I read about Deserialization / Serialization from a couple of websites but still can't achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve doing this why not create a list of class and deserialize every json object to the list?

Comment: Is it possible? Will the data go to each field dynamically? I mean in runtime? If so, please show me how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629812/deserializing-json-string-to-vb-net-object